# Replicating matlab filter in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signal-processing

I am re-writing a matlab filter script into python and have vastly different outputs. Does anyone know how to make these functions similar?

There was some preliminary calculations made to find the equivalent ripple and other factors.

Python Script:

```
from scipy import signal
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

# Variable Values:
total_ripple = -20*m.log10(0.001) #get decibels
fsamp = 100
Nyqu = fsamp/2
trans_width = (0.7 - 0.1)/Nyqu
cut = (0.7+0.1)/2*(Nyqu)

# Script:
numtaps, beta = signal.kaiserord(total_ripple, trans_width)
taps = signal.firwin(numtaps, cutoff=cut, width = trans_width,  fs = fsamp, window=('kaiser',numtaps+1, beta), scale=False, pass_zero=True)
filtered_data = (signal.lfilter(taps, 1, data1, axis = 0)).tolist()
```

Matlab Script:

```
mags = [1, 0]
devs = [0.001, 0.1]
fcuts = [0.1 0.7]
fsamp = 100
[n,Wn,beta,ftype] = kaiserord(fcuts,mags,devs,fsamp);
hh = fir1(n,Wn,ftype,kaiser(n+1,beta),'noscale');
filteredData = filter(hh,1,data);
```

(Edit: added variable values)
I know that the fcuts will vary between matlab and python. Python only accepts a single fcuts value in decibels for stopband. Simply plotting taps & hh gives different plots. The final plots with the actual data is different as well.

Comment: Does the Matlab script generate a correct filter for you?   Give an example with actual values for `fcuts`, `mags`, `devs` and `fsamp` in the Matlab script, and show the result `hh`.   Then show how you translated those values to the Python script, and show `taps` to let us verify that the outputs are "vastly different".  In other words, provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then it will be much easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Thanks warren. i added edits.

Answer (score 1):

Took some guess and testing but I figured out an equivalence for a Kaiser window (going from Scipy to MATLAB, at least). If your python code for a 40 Hz Kaiser window with transition width of 5 is:

```
freq = 40.
trans_width = 5.
sampling_rate = 2000.
nyquist = sampling_rate/2
ntaps40, beta40 = kaiserord(freq, trans_width/nyquist)
```

the MATLAB equivalent is:

```
[ntaps40,W,beta40] = kaiserord([freq-trans_width/2 freq+trans_width/2],[1 0],2*trans_width/nyquist*[1 1],sampling_rate)
```

Note: I have no idea why you need the factor of 2 for 2*trans_width! I can just tell you the ntaps and beta are the same in scipy and MATLAB.